# How to write the grammar for this in pyparsing: match a set of words but not containing a given pattern

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am new to Python and pyparsing.  I need to accomplish the following.

My sample line of text is like this:

```
12 items - Ironing Service    11 Mar 2009 to 10 Apr 2009
Washing service (3 Shirt)  23 Mar 2009
```

I need to extract the item description, period

```
tok_date_in_ddmmmyyyy = Combine(Word(nums,min=1,max=2)+ " " + Word(alphas, exact=3) + " " + Word(nums,exact=4))
tok_period = Combine((tok_date_in_ddmmmyyyy + " to " + tok_date_in_ddmmmyyyy)|tok_date_in_ddmmmyyyy)

tok_desc =  Word(alphanums+"-()") but stop before tok_period
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest looking at SkipTo as the pyparsing class that is most appropriate, since you have a good definition of the *unwanted* text, but will accept pretty much anything before that.  Here are a couple of ways to use SkipTo:

```
text = """\
12 items - Ironing Service    11 Mar 2009 to 10 Apr 2009
Washing service (3 Shirt)  23 Mar 2009"""

# using tok_period as defined in the OP

# parse each line separately
for tx in text.splitlines():
    print SkipTo(tok_period).parseString(tx)[0]

# or have pyparsing search through the whole input string using searchString
for [[td,_]] in SkipTo(tok_period,include=True).searchString(text):
    print td
```

Both `for` loops print the following:

```
12 items - Ironing Service    
Washing service (3 Shirt)
```

Comment: Thanks Paul for pointing me to the right class and for the code snippet.

Answer (score 3):

M K Saravanan, this particular parsing problem is not so hard to do with good 'ole re:

```
import re
import string

text='''
12 items - Ironing Service    11 Mar 2009 to 10 Apr 2009
Washing service (3 Shirt)  23 Mar 2009
This line does not match
'''

date_pat=re.compile(
    r'(\d{1,2}\s+[a-zA-Z]{3}\s+\d{4}(?:\s+to\s+\d{1,2}\s+[a-zA-Z]{3}\s+\d{4})?)')
for line in text.splitlines():
    if line:
        try:
            description,period=map(string.strip,date_pat.split(line)[:2])
            print((description,period))
        except ValueError:
            # The line does not match
            pass
```

yields

```
# ('12 items - Ironing Service', '11 Mar 2009 to 10 Apr 2009')
# ('Washing service (3 Shirt)', '23 Mar 2009')
```

The main workhorse here is of course the re pattern. Let's break it apart:

`\d{1,2}\s+[a-zA-Z]{3}\s+\d{4}` is the regexp for a date, the equivalent of `tok_date_in_ddmmmyyyy`. `\d{1,2}` matches one or two digits, `\s+` matches one or more whitespaces, `[a-zA-Z]{3}` matches 3 letters, etc.

`(?:\s+to\s+\d{1,2}\s+[a-zA-Z]{3}\s+\d{4})?` is a regexp surrounded by `(?:...)`.
This indicates a non-grouping regexp. Using this, no group (e.g. match.group(2)) is assigned to this regexp. This matters because date_pat.split() returns a list with each group being a member of the list. By suppressing the grouping, we keep the entire period `11 Mar 2009 to 10 Apr 2009` together. The question mark at the end indicates that this pattern may occur zero or once. This allows the regexp to match both
`23 Mar 2009` and `11 Mar 2009 to 10 Apr 2009`.

`text.splitlines()` splits text on `\n`.

`date_pat.split('12 items - Ironing Service    11 Mar 2009 to 10 Apr 2009')`

splits the string on the date_pat regexp. The match is included in the returned list.
Thus we get:

`['12 items - Ironing Service    ', '11 Mar 2009 to 10 Apr 2009', '']`

`map(string.strip,date_pat.split(line)[:2])` prettifies the result.

If `line` does not match `date_pat`, then `date_pat.split(line)` returns `[line,]`,
so

`description,period=map(string.strip,date_pat.split(line)[:2])`

raises a ValueError because we can't unpack a list with only one element into a 2-tuple. We catch this exception but simply pass on to the next line.